# Bug in CSS3 box-shadow after scrolling in Opera

Tags: opera, css

Anybody familiar with this bug with box-shadow in CSS3?

It renders ok at first. But when scrolling the page up and down(so the shadows goes in and out of visible area) the shadows from the horizontal lines does error and needs to be reloaded to render right. I experience this only in Opera, and not in IE(where I use css3pie.com).

Take look at this example: http://www.gatzschmann.no/beta/

Anybody got a clue why? This does not happen when viewing other sites using box-shadow.

Regards
Petter Andreas

Comment: That link says 403 Forbidden to me..

Comment: yes, i moved it to the root folder for the domain. Check http://www.gatzschmann.no/ Besides, i guess this is a bug in Opera, and will be fixed in later updates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a redraw painting bug in Opera. We're aware of this issue and we'll fix it as soon as we can.